# How can I keep my storm door from dragging on the threshold?

Tags: doors, hinges

I have an aluminium double glazed door that has dropped slightly and is dragging in the lower corner opposite the hinges.

I can't see how to adjust these hinges.  Under the black dust caps there is just a black plastic piece with a small round hole: no hex or screw. Is it possible to adjust these? If so, how? If not, how can I stop the door sticking?

[image: aluminium flag hinge]

[image: flag hinge, inside]

Update: the door frame is a single metal frame.  The hinges each screw into a steel plate which is free to slide up and down inside the frame when the screws are loosened.  The black plastic is just separate pieces of clip-on cover.
[image]

Comment: Is the black plastic thing a block that the screws are in? You may be able to loosen all of them (not just 1 hinge) slide the door up and tighten them. Strut clamps work this way it would be that or adding a new shim under each pin as those may have worn.

Comment: You've asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Your proposed solution isn't the right one--unless hinges are severely worn they usually shouldn't be raised. Instead, ask about the actual problem, which is more likely resolved by tightening jamb attachment at the upper hinge.

Comment: To that end, please show is a wider view of the jamb situation.

Comment: @EdBeal you were right.  If you would like to answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested : Is the black plastic thing a block that the screws are in? You may be able to loosen all of them (not just 1 hinge) slide the door up and tighten them. Strut clamps work this way it would be that or adding a new shim under each pin as those may have worn.

Comment: The plastic was just a cover, but there were steel blocks that the hinges screwed into. These could slide in the door frame. Loosening all the screws allowed me to slide the door back up a couple of mm.

Answer (score 2):

**Try tightening attachment of hinge to door and jamb.**

If the attachment gets loose the door can sag.  It looks like you are missing a screw on the jamb side; center hole is empty.  I cannot imagine anyone would throw out a funky screw like this so maybe the escapee is still nearby in a drawer.

You should be able to tighten these with a hex wrench.  It might help to have an assistant lift the door slightly to oppose the sag and take the weight off the hinges when you tighten them.

Tighten all of them.  If there is a way to tell which hinge is the culprit I don't know it.

If this works that is great but it will happen again.  You might need to augment the holes in door and jamb to get a tighter purchase.

Comment: Use care when tightening, especially the screws that go into the door. If they're just through sheet metal, the threads can strip easily. These cap-head bolts have a look that says that there are actually nuts welded into the frame for them to screw into, though, so it shouldn't be a problem. It may be worth removing both bolts from the door side of the hinge and taking a look at what's behind the leaf, just so you've got an idea. Should only take a minute to do so, and, once they're been retightened, there will be no sign anything's been done.

Comment: All the screws were tight and there wasn't any play.  Turns out the whole lot had just slid fractionally down inside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, as a last resort, try a tension wire. They're sold in the big box stores or any local hardware store as screen door adjustment kits.